Spring - Reactive code - Change not propagating
I am trying to understand the propagation of reactive streams and how it plays
So the usecase is lets say I have list of bookings which I am grouping by age and processing the list of bookings by age. Its very important that I use collectList to later on group by age. I tried group and collectMAp of flux and both were not working for me. So I did collectList and then did group by using stream
Now for each booking set (grouped by age), I am trying to process booking individually (This is not actual code but to simplify I made such example). I process booking and then return Mono.empty once all bookings are processed.
Here is the code
@GetMapping("/test")
 public Mono<Void> test() {
   return prepareForBooking();
 }

 @Data
 public class  Booking {
   String name;
   String age;
 }
 private Mono<Void> prepareForBooking() {
   System.out.println("Booking::1");
   Booking booking = new Booking();
   booking.setName("San");
   booking.setAge("18");

   Booking booking1 = new Booking();
   booking1.setName("Man");
   booking1.setAge("19");

   Booking booking2 = new Booking();
   booking2.setName("Dan");
   booking2.setAge("18");

   Booking booking3 = new Booking();
   booking3.setName("Can");
   booking3.setAge("17");

   List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
   bookings.add(booking);
   bookings.add(booking1);
   bookings.add(booking2);
   bookings.add(booking3);

   return Flux.fromIterable(bookings)
           .collectList()
           .map(
                   bookingList -> {
                     var bookingsByAge =
                             bookingList.stream()
                                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::getAge));

                     return bookingsByAge.keySet().stream()
                             .map(
                                     age -> {
                                       if (age.equals("18") || age.equals("17")) {
                                         return processBookings(bookingsByAge.get(age));
                                       } else {
                                         return Mono.empty();
                                       }
                                     });
                   })
           .flatMapMany(Flux::fromStream)
           .then();
 }

 private Mono<Void> processBookings(List<Booking> bookings) {

   System.out.println("Booking::2" + bookings);
   return Flux.fromIterable(bookings).flatMap(booking -> this.processBooking(booking)).collectList().flatMap(bookingNames -> {
     System.out.println("Booking::4" + bookingNames);
     return Mono.empty();
   });
 }

 private Mono<String> processBooking(Booking booking) {
   System.out.println("Booking::3" + booking.getName());
   return Mono.just(booking.getName());
 }

What I get as output
Booking::1
Booking::2[ProviderIntegrationBookingController.Booking(name=Can, age=17)]
Booking::2[ProviderIntegrationBookingController.Booking(name=San, age=18), ProviderIntegrationBookingController.Booking(name=Dan, age=18)]

What I was expecting is
Booking::1
Booking::2[ProviderIntegrationBookingController.Booking(name=Can, age=17)]
Booking::2[ProviderIntegrationBookingController.Booking(name=San, age=18), ProviderIntegrationBookingController.Booking(name=Dan, age=18)]
Booking::3 San
Booking::3 Dan
Booking::3 Can
Booking::4 [Can]
Booking::4 [San, Dan]

So I am not sure how I could make the code inide processBookings work after print statement and I dont want to subscribe (as that solves the issue but I think is not right way). I was expecting the chaining to work
My doubt is on collectList where I have to make map of age and bookings

Is it important for you to, at the end, collect that list as a list of bookings and solely generate side effects (such as System.out.println), or do you want to transform it as a list of, let's say, BookingResult ?

Also, is the order in which you want to handle bookings important? For instance if you have an unordered list, do you expect all younger persons to be handled before older ones?

Few things are making this hard to read:

the code you are writing does not seem functional and instead seems to generates many side effects; is that what you really want?
then .then() at the end of your pipeline completely shades one of your most helpful friend when using generics: compilation checks on types

What I suggest from my very little experience with WebFlux and generics overall is that you first write your code as returning an actually typed result, so that you can ensure you have a valid subscription chain. Then, eventually, if you want to mask the result at some point, plonk that result by mapping it to something else.
Here is was I would have done to, instead of generating side effects, returning a result for each of your booking requests:

Disclaimer: I am fairly positive you can find a much better and clearer version of this code, I am not very fluent with WebFlux.

  @GetMapping("/test")
  public Mono<List<BookingResult>> test() {
    // add a .then() here if you really want to return a Mono<Void>
    return prepareForBooking();
  }

  public record Booking(String name, String age) {

  }

  public record BookingResult(Booking booking, Status status) {

    public enum Status {
      SUCCESS,
      FAILURE,
      ;
    }

  }

  private Mono<List<BookingResult>> prepareForBooking() {
    System.out.println("Booking::1");

    Booking booking0 = new Booking("San", "18");
    Booking booking1 = new Booking("Man", "19");
    Booking booking2 = new Booking("Dan", "18");
    Booking booking3 = new Booking("Can", "17");

    List<Booking> bookings = new ArrayList<>();
    bookings.add(booking0);
    bookings.add(booking1);
    bookings.add(booking2);
    bookings.add(booking3);

    return Flux.fromIterable(bookings)
               .collectList()
               .map(bookingList -> bookingList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Booking::age)))
               .flatMap(bookingsByAge -> bookingsByAge.entrySet()
                                                      .stream()
                                                      .map(this::bookForValidCustomers)
                                                      .reduce(Flux.<BookingResult>empty(),
                                                              (listMono, listMono2) -> listMono.mergeWith(Flux.fromIterable(listMono2)
                                                                                                              .flatMap(Function.identity())),
                                                              Flux::mergeWith)
                                                      .collectList());
  }

  private List<Mono<BookingResult>> bookForValidCustomers(final Entry<String, List<Booking>> entry) {
    if (entry.getKey().equals("18") || entry.getKey().equals("17")) {
      return processBookings(entry.getValue());
    } else {
      return failBookings(entry.getValue());
    }
  }

  private List<Mono<BookingResult>> processBookings(List<Booking> bookings) {
    System.out.println("SuccessPath::2" + bookings);
    return bookings.stream()
                   .map(this::processBooking)
                   .toList();
  }

  private Mono<BookingResult> processBooking(Booking booking) {
    System.out.println("SuccessPath::3" + booking.name());
    return Mono.just(new BookingResult(booking, Status.SUCCESS));
  }

  private List<Mono<BookingResult>> failBookings(List<Booking> bookings) {
    System.out.println("FailurePath::2" + bookings);
    return bookings.stream()
                   .map(this::failBooking)
                   .toList();
  }

  private Mono<BookingResult> failBooking(Booking booking) {
    System.out.println("FailurePath::3" + booking.name());
    return Mono.just(new BookingResult(booking, Status.FAILURE));
  }

which does the following:
➜  ~ curl --silent -X GET --location "http://localhost:8080/test" | jq
[
  {
    "booking": {
      "name": "Can",
      "age": "17"
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  },
  {
    "booking": {
      "name": "San",
      "age": "18"
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  },
  {
    "booking": {
      "name": "Dan",
      "age": "18"
    },
    "status": "SUCCESS"
  },
  {
    "booking": {
      "name": "Man",
      "age": "19"
    },
    "status": "FAILURE"
  }
]

and generates the following side effects:
Booking::1
SuccessPath::2[Booking[name=Can, age=17]]
SuccessPath::3Can
SuccessPath::2[Booking[name=San, age=18], Booking[name=Dan, age=18]]
SuccessPath::3San
SuccessPath::3Dan
FailurePath::2[Booking[name=Man, age=19]]
FailurePath::3Man

